# SQLite database is locked?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, process, sql-insert

I just tried to add row into SQLite database and text part includes "/" character.

This is how i do connection:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;

this.db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    db.beginTransaction();

    ..............................
    insertion stuffs
    ..............................

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
```

After that insert when I try to insert new row, app crashes and gives me this error on logcat:

```
08-24 19:01:09.477  27064-27064/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) POSIX Error : 11 SQLite Error : 3850
08-24 19:01:09.477  27064-27064/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) database is locked
Process: .MyService, PID: 17827
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

**Is it because slash characther or what? It worked well before that one row insertion or is my table corrupted?**

Comment: are you sure you closed all your other db instances before adding it in?

Comment: @tyczj, I added sqlite transaction methods i use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forget to [close the connection to database](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Connection.htm), and invoke the method [endTransaction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29).

Comment: In the reverse order: you FIRST end the transaction, and THEN close the connection.

Comment: I actually do endTransaction, but somehow I can't produce this error anymore.

Comment: @EspeH I think it was a pending transaction that caused the locking of the db.